# Cat hissing / but can be close to other cat?

Tags: cats, behavior, training

So Woody (young adult boy cat) can almost touch noses when Dizzy (2.5 year old boy cat) jumps up on to the bed and there's no hissing.

(We've had Woody since he was a kitten and just got Dizzy two weeks ago. We also have a much older female cat who keeps things to herself but occasionally hisses at both and sometimes chased by Woody, but that's another story.)

They can also eat close to each other, when we feed them wet food close to each other.

But Woody will hiss at Dizzy when in close proximity at other times.

Also Dizzy can occasionally chase after Woody once he's been spooked by Dizzy.

We guess Woody must get frightened of Dizzy, hence the hissing.

Can anyone explain this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hissing can just be "don't crowd me, I'm not in the mood to deal with you right now".

They'll negotiate something. It may or may not get quieter.

Comment: Thanks, Dizzy also seems to stalk the litter tray until the cat darts out. Do you mean that shouldn't intervene?

Answer (score 1):

Hissing is an attempt to intimidate the other cat into leaving (or at least not approaching any closer) because the cat is scared but wants to avoid a fight. If the other cat continues to approach, the hissing cat may either attack or run, which builds distrust. If the other cat stops or leaves, though, that begins to build trust and each time it will be allowed to get a little closer.